# Sailsjs Mysql ORM multiple query on the same table field

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

Im using sails v 0.10.5 and latest sails-mysql

I have a Restaurant filtering system

```
Venue.find().populate('comments', {
        deleted: false
    }).where({
            restaurant_services: {contains: '"delivery":1'},
            restaurant_services: {contains: '"takeout":1'},
            restaurant_specialties: {contains: '"breakfast":1'}
    })
```

Now the problem is when I get the data from the client, I do not know how many items the user has selected for restaurat_services, so obviously I have to create a dynamic JSON object for the .where() function

The problem is though, I cannot do this

```
var searchObj = {};
searchObj['restaurant_specialties'] = {contains: '"breakfast":1'};
```

`searchObj['restaurant_specialties'] = {contains: '"breakfast":1'};`

So as you may see the previous setting of the value gets replaced the second time,

Any help would be greatly appreciated from the Smart people out there[here](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/query-language.md#in-pairs)
but does not work

```
Model.find({
  name: { 'contains' : ['Walter', 'Skyler'] }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Venue.find().populate('comments', {
    deleted: false
}).where({
        restaurant_services: {
            contains: '"delivery":1',
            contains: '"takeout":1',
        },
        restaurant_specialties: {contains: '"breakfast":1'}
})
```

that you need

```
Venue.find({
  where:{
    restaurant_services: {
      contains: '"delivery":1',
      contains: '"takeout":1',
    },
    restaurant_specialties: {
      contains: '"breakfast":"1"'
    }
  }
}).populate('comments', {
    deleted: false
}).exec(console.log);
```

Comment: Ok Cool, Can you tell me how to generate this query inside the where() function please ? This is the challenge bro, Because sometime there could be 5 restaurant_specialties

Comment: This does not filter the data for some reason, I sometime get records with "delivery":"0" :(

Comment: @user3656084 Can you post you sql script, that I can know what you need, Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Thats ok @zieglar I got my results using raw sql Venue.query()

Comment: ``Venue.query('SELECT * FROM `venue` WHERE ' ( `restaurant_services` LIKE '%"delivery":"1"%' AND `restaurant_services` LIKE '%"reserve":"1"%' ) AND (`restaurant_specialties` LIKE '%"breakfast":"1"%' ) ``

Comment: I generate this query dynamically using `` req.param.all() ``

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this based on how waterline works you need different fields to search on.

You can do this by created aliased attributes in your model.

```
venue.js
module.exports.attributes = {
    restaurant_services:'string',
    restaurant_services_1: {type:'string',columnName: 'restaurant_services'}
    restaurant_services_2: {type:'string',columnName: 'restaurant_services'}
    restaurant_services_3: {type:'string',columnName: 'restaurant_services'}
    restaurant_services_4: {type:'string',columnName: 'restaurant_services'}
    restaurant_services_5: {type:'string',columnName: 'restaurant_services'}
}
```

Then you can do

```
Venue.find().populate('comments', {
        deleted: false
    }).where({
            restaurant_services: {contains: '"delivery":1'},
            restaurant_services_1: {contains: '"takeout":1'},
            restaurant_specialties: {contains: '"breakfast":1'}
    })
```

Its hacky, but it works

Comment: This seems too hacky Meeker and too confusing, Im sure you are smarter than me, but I do not like this, Should you think I should save the restaurant_specialities as a STRING not as a JSON on the DB ?

Comment: I have 9 restaurant_services. So do I have to create 9 attributes in the Venue Model ? Is there a dynamic way to create attributes in the Model ?

Comment: I just tried this. Does not work for some reason Meeker, Im so confused why, I still get the records with "delivery":"0", I really need some help bro

Comment: There is a issue here @Meeker, o this is the query right, I ran this query about 30 times and saw a pattern, The pattern was that only the last key:value was taken in to consideration, All the other key: values on top are ignored by the ORM.

I think this question may have become an actual issue in Waterline.

Please let me know what you think

Cheers mate